# preg_replace search for string that does not match the pattern instead of string that match the pattern

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, bbcode

I have this array of possible values that I want to replace with `preg_replace` function:

```
$attr = array('b','i','u','left','center','right');

foreach($attr as $a) {
    // strip bbcode
    $str = preg_replace('#\['.$a.'\](.*)\[/'.$a.'\]#im','$1',$str); 
}
return $str;
```

but instead of using foreach and looping through each possible exclusion, I want to do it like strip anything that isn't an `img` instead. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean you want to strip out all tags except **img** tags? Use this:

```
$str = preg_replace('#\[(?!/?img).+?]#im','',$str);
```

Comment: your pattern works for me though there was error in your code. says 'preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash', if fixed it by adding delimeters. thanks btw

Comment: Oh, sorry about that...I tested the regex at a PowerShell prompt (no regex delimiters in PS, just quotes) and copied from there. I'll add the delimiters and mode modifiers to fix the answer for posterity.